# htaccess current folder 777

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is there a way to make an .htaccess folder to change permission for the current folder it's in and allow PHP execution? The server admin has a re-write to disallow php extensions in all directories.

I have:
[site]/forum/

and

[site]/forum/index.php

index.php won't be executed due to 500 error.

Would I use AllowOverride FileInfo, or something along those lines? I've never used htaccess before.

Comment: Check your error logs to see what is causing the 500 error.

Comment: No. htaccess is for changing server configuration at a local level. It has nothing to do with file permissions. Even if it could, setting world read/write/execute (777) is a bad idea.

Comment: @Cfreak He didn't disable php he just removed access unless in htaccess. He said it can be changed alonged the lines AllowOverride but he's offline atm. :/

Answer (score 2):

`AllowOverride FileInfo` can only be used in the server/vhost config, and is used to determine what server configuration an htaccess file can override. You can't change file permissions from htaccess.

You might by able to set a handler type like:

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php
```

or

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

But not having those won't cause your 500 error. If this was purely a file permissions issue, you'd simply get a 403 Forbidden response, not a 500. Not just that, if PHP wasn't being executed, you'd simply see the contents of the `index.php` file, not a 500 error.

Something else is causing your error.

Comment: Exact error: Directory "/home/accounts/1014801048/site/forum" is writeable by group

Comment: @Jakes625 You need to change the permissions of that directory to `755`. If you have shell access, use `chmod`, if not, try [a google search for dozens of possible options](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=how+to+change+file+permissions+ftp&oq=how+to+change+file+permissions+ftp)